# Issue with build_nav_icon helper with blueprint plugin on CKAN 2.7

Tags: ckan

I recently made my first plugin using the IBlueprint interface, and have been using it successfully on CKAN 2.8. I attempted to deploy it to a system running 2.7.6 (we have postponed updating to 2.8 until a couple other items are ready, but though this would drop in) and encountered an issue with the build_nav_icon template helper function.

We are trying to add a dataset navigation menu entry, and the function call within my read_base.html template is:

```
h.build_nav_icon('relationships.read', _('Relationships'), dataset_id=pkg.name, icon='connectdevelop')
```

relationships.read links to a blueprint entry, and this all works on 2.8, but 2.7 returns:

> File
>   '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-relationshipdisplay/ckanext/relationshipdisplay/templates/package/read_base.html',
>   line 5 in block "content_primary_nav"    {{
>   h.build_nav_icon('relationships.read', _('Relationships'),
>   dataset_id=pkg.name, icon='connectdevelop')}}
>
> File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/helpers.py', line 672
>   in build_nav_icon    return _make_menu_item(menu_item, title, **kw)
>
> File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/helpers.py', line 729
>   in _make_menu_item    raise Exception('menu item `%s` cannot be found'
>   % menu_item)
>
> Exception: menu item `relationships.read` cannot be found

Looking at the CKAN code a bit it appears the make_menu_item function only references pylons based routes. Is there a workaround to make this work on 2.7 or something I may have overlooked in my plugin configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CKAN 2.7 you need create and connect the controller like in https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/2.7/ckanext/datastore/controller.py and https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/2.7/ckanext/datastore/plugin.py#L157

```py
from ckan.plugins.toolkit import BaseController

class RelationshipdisplayController(BaseController):
  def someactionhere(self):
    return ''
```

```py
  def before_map(self, m):
            'relationships.read', '/someurlhere',
            controller='ckanext.relationshipdisplay.controller.RelationshipdisplayController',
            action='someactionhere', ckan_icon='connectdevelop')
        return m
```

EDIT:

Reason for implementing pylons based controller is that most of the flask support in 2.7 does not exist yet. The only migrated controller in the core is the api and that doesn't require pretty much anything from the helpers.

Comment: Thanks, it was unclear from the change log what the level of Flask / Blueprint support was in 2.7 and I thought there might be simple workaround.